# Read And Search CSV File To Load Back Into Multiple Textboxes (Help/Confused)

Tags: visual-studio, csv

I don’t know why I’ve been struggling with this for so long, but I’ve recently come back to visual basic after being away from Visual Basic 6.0 for numerous years and I am relearning as needed for this app.

I’ve made an order form and can write to the csv file no problem which I will later open in excel to read. Everything looks great. But now I need a way to search for a name and load the csv line associated with it back into the text boxes (including which checkboxes were checked) so it can be edited and then rewritten back to the csv file on the same line with the changes. Any help please?

I’ve been reading a lot about how to load text and csv files back in, but it’s the arrays that are confusing me, which I believe are used to separate the text between “,” and put into individual text boxes. I don't know where to start.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim LineOfText As String
    Dim intArray As Integer
    Dim aryCommaSplit() As String
    Dim FileData As StreamReader = File.OpenText(FILE_NAME)

    LineOfText = FileData.ReadLine
    aryCommaSplit = LineOfText.Split(",")

    'Outputs first line of .csv file (First, Second, Third) into three textboxes
    For intArray = 0 To UBound(aryCommaSplit)
        TextBox1.Text = aryCommaSplit(0)
        TextBox2.Text = aryCommaSplit(1)
        TextBox3.Text = aryCommaSplit(2)
    Next intArray
End Sub
```

EDIT: Thank you for the SPLIT Function. I experimented with it. So with this code, I can read back the top line of a .csv file and place it into individual textboxes. Great, but how do I read other lines? Specifically, search for a name, which would be the first item on each line and if correct, load that line into each text box.

I'm guessing the code for this would be a loop with an array that reads each line. At the same time, looking for the name until it reaches it and loads into the textboxes with the above code.

Comment: I removed your image link. It was irrelevant to the question you've asked. What your user interface looks like has nothing to do with the question you've asked. Images should only be used when absolutely necessary to demonstrate a problem that can't be explained any other way. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the reasons *not* to include images.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for that.

Comment: So, is this VBA or VB6? Tag appropriately in order to reach the people with knowledge that can help you. VBA = Office; Visual Studio means "NET", these days. Use a VB6 tag if you mean VB6 (the [edit] link below your question will allow you to change/add information). Also, please read the guidelines for posting questions in the [help]: you don't really provide enough information (code and csv file content) for us to visualize what you have and what you need. "but it’s the arrays that are confusing me": What arrays? Are you looking for th `Split` function?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio. I'm going to update my question with the code of a test I'm using to read and display into the textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I no have it finding a word within the .csv file that is entered into textbox1. It then tells me the line number and enters a line into textbox1, textbox2, and textbox3. However, it is always the first line. How do I tell it to use the line (i) from the line number I find earlier? I can't put it in the For intArray. Do I create another?

EDIT: Nevermind. I figured it out! EXCEPT, how can I rewrite back to the same line it was found on?

```
Dim Lookfor As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim aryCommaSplit() As String
    Dim aryLineRead() As String
    'aryCommaSplit = LineOfText.Split(",")
    'aryLineRead = aryCommaSplit
    Dim intArray As Integer
    Dim currentline As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        currentline = i
        aryCommaSplit = lines(i).Split(",")
        aryLineRead = aryCommaSplit
        'Searches for word entered in TextBox1 within the open .csv file
        If lines(i).Contains(Lookfor) Then
            For intArray = 0 To UBound(aryLineRead)
                TextBox1.Text = aryCommaSplit(0)
                TextBox2.Text = aryCommaSplit(1)
                TextBox3.Text = aryCommaSplit(2)
            Next

            'Writes the line number to Label1
            Label1.Text = currentline
            'Writes the full line to TextBox5
            TextBox5.Text = lines(i)
        End If
    Next
```